# import csv file into mysql with custom data change

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I have a .csv file contains data like this:

```
Username   Password   Email
test123    123        test@foobar.com
```

I'm currently using MySQL, and I have a table named `user` with some columns like this:

```
UserID    Username    Password    Email
```

What i'm looking for is how can I import my csv data into `user` table and convert password column with MD5 method so what I have at the last is

```
UserID    Username    Password                          Email
1          test123     202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70  test@foobar.com
```

NB: I have a hundred record in my csv file.
Any help please. Thanks for advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use `md5` for password hashing.

Comment: @kelunik Why I shouldn't? Any explanation please?

Comment: Because it's unsafe, there are a lot of resources out there, just use your favorite search engine. One example: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908

Comment: Thanks for advice. Maybe I'll make a change for my system later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to write a small script that reads that file and executes some queries to import these data sets.

If you want to use PHP (just one example, [more information here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)) it would be something like:

```
    <?php

    $db = new PDO($connectStr, $username, $password);
    $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...)");

    $file = file_get_contents(...);
    $lines = explode("\n", $file);

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $data = explode(";", $line);
        // manipulate password here, for PHP, use password_hash instead of md5
        $q->execute([$data]);
    }
    ?>
```

Another promising solution could be `LOAD DATA INFILE`.
You should have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What's below works for your data - be careful of any variation in the field width - that's why delimited files are better - csv, or better still, if you can get it, pipe-delimited (|). It also successfully deals with the header line.

I did the following:

My code will do for both MD5 and SHA2 passwords - uncomment the relevant bits.

```
CREATE TABLE my_user
(
  user_id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  username varchar(11), 
  p_word varchar(64), -- VARCHAR(32) for MD5
  e_mail varchar(75)
);
```

using a sample based on your data (users.csv)

```
$> more users.csv;
Username   Password   Email
test123    123        test@foobar.com
test456    567        sdfsd@blah.com
$>
```

And then after some [Googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461790/loading-fixed-width-space-delimited-txt-file-into-mysql), I came up with this

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE '/mysql/mdb5.5/inst/users.csv'
INTO TABLE my_user
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@row)
SET username = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,  1, 11)),
    -- p_word   = MD5(TRIM(SUBSTR(@row, 12, 22))), 
    p_word = SHA2(TRIM(SUBSTR(@row, 12, 11)), 256),
    e_mail  = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row, 23, 80))
;
```

And voilà!

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from my_user;
+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| user_id | username | p_word                                                           | e_mail          |
+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|       1 | test123  | a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3 | test@foobar.com |
|       2 | test456  | 97a6d21df7c51e8289ac1a8c026aaac143e15aa1957f54f42e30d8f8a85c3a55 | sdfsd@blah.com  |
+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Impressive!! +1 pal, another solution!